# Integer to Ros::time

Tags: ros, rostime

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I have a txt file with encoderdata and timestamps. I am reading from this file and want to put this timestamps in variables declared as Ros::time, but I cant manage to get this right. Is it possible to do this?  The timestamp is coming from a msg like this.

```
ros::Time current_time_encoder;
current_time_encoder = msg->angle_timestamp1;
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/232457/integer-to-ros::time/) by [Bert](https://answers.ros.org/users/26233/bert/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2016-04-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2016-04-21**:
The essential question here is: What does the int mean?

**Comment by [Bert](https://answers.ros.org/users/26233/bert/) on 2016-04-21**:
What do you mean?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2016-04-21**:
What does a time stamp of "5" mean for you? You'll have to convert this correctly. Check @Martin Günther s answer for reasonable guesses.

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2016-04-21**:
Right. I (perhaps incorrectly) assumed that it's seconds/milliseconds/... since 1970-01-01 00:00. If not, you need to add/subtract an offset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So `msg->angle_timestamp1` is an int, right?

If it's time in seconds (which is not a good idea, because the resolution is way too coarse), this should work:

```
ros::Time current_time_encoder(msg->angle_timestamp1);
```

If it's nanoseconds, this works:

```
ros::Time current_time_encoder(msg->angle_timestamp1 / 1e9, msg->angle_timestamp1 % 1e9);
```

Similarly 1e6 for microseconds, 1e3 for milliseconds.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2016-04-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [r7vme](https://answers.ros.org/users/39591/r7vme/) on 2019-03-08**:
thanks! small correction: e.g. for milliseconds we also need to multiply by 1e6.

```
  int nsecs = (msg->angle_timestamp1 % 1000) * 1000 * 1000;
  int secs = msg->angle_timestamp1 / 1000;
  ros::Time state_timestamp(secs, nsecs);
```